# I need to extract data from one column where condition matches from another column using index and match

Tags: excel

In this sheet, I have a range in `B1:C18`, where I want to return `column C` values in `G column` where all values match with `column B` with the condition value in `E1`.

But I'm getting only top value from the Column C but not all (i.e., `Sep 2` has two values `443` and `472`) but it is returning only `443`.

Could anyone look at the formula return in `G1` as

`={IF(ISERROR(INDEX($B$1:$C$18,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$18=$E$1,ROW($B$1:$B$18)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",
INDEX($B$1:$C$18,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$18=$E$1,ROW($B$1:$B$18)),ROW(1:1)),2))}`.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Comment: @RussellB Thanks for the comments, i have edited, if thats okay could you please look at it now.

Answer (score 0):

> **Get the Answers in a column**

Ok, I checked and your formula and it is correct too. I have modified it to be an `ArrayFormula` in the Google Sheets. Just check.

**Formula 1**

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ISERROR(INDEX($B$1:$C$18,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$18=$E$1,ROW($B$1:$B$18)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"", INDEX($B$1:$C$18,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$18=$E$1,ROW($B$1:$B$18)),ROW(1:1)),2)))`

You can try this formula too -

**Formula 2**

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$18, SMALL(IF(E$1=$B$1:$B$18, ROW($C$1:$C$18),""), ROW())),""))`

Just copy the formula in the cells of the respective column and you are good to go.

> **Get the Answers in a single cell**

Use this Array Formula for your Google Sheets -

`=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(B1:B18 = E1,C1:C18,"")))`

It will aggregate all the values in a single cell.

Comment: I want results in different cells

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for that but if i have more no.of matching results i need to pull that many formula columns, can we have all the matching results in a single formula

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: for each value i need to drag the formula then only it is returning all the matching values

Comment: Yes, because you need it in new cells, and if that cell doesn't have a formula, then there will not be any value... So, it need's to be in the cells that you want the value in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
=iferror(split(textjoin(", ", 1, filter(C2:C, B2:B=E1)), ", ", 1))
```

and see if that works ?

Comment: I want to work this in excel, as filter function will not appllicable for excel. So could you please rewrite it in terms of excel.